# Customize Junit 4 XML report

Tags: java, gradle, junit, testng

Background:

TestNG supports adding your own Reporter classes in order to modify the reports being generated or generating new reports as needed.

However, JUnit doesn't have such a functionality, so a brute-force way would be to write your own Runner and then generate your own custom report.

But, I ask this question in order to find if there is something better?

Basically, I want to add custom attribute to every executed method.

```
<testcase name="test_test_something" classname="some.class.name" time="0.069" my-own-attribute="somevalue"/>
```

So my question is:

- How is this XML report generated by JUnit and Gradle?
- Is there a way to modify this process of report generation to add custom data to the report while doing minimal changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is this XML report generated by JUnit and Gradle?

It’s eventually generated by the Gradle internal class [`org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.result.JUnitXmlResultWriter`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/5c162f34bfe037bf8a51b387bbccb48c290856ed/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/junit/result/JUnitXmlResultWriter.java).

> Basically, I want to add custom attribute to every executed method.
>
> ```
> <testcase name="test_test_something" classname="some.class.name" time="0.069" my-own-attribute="somevalue"/>
> ```
>
> […]
>   Is there a way to modify this process of report generation to add custom data to the report while doing minimal changes?

Unfortunately, there is no way to add further attributes to the `<testcase/>` element. [This code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/5c162f34bfe037bf8a51b387bbccb48c290856ed/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/junit/result/JUnitXmlResultWriter.java#L95-L98) shows how the element and its attributes are currently created; there is no way to hook into that creation process.

---

If you can live with a hacky solution, then you could try writing your custom data to StdOut/StdErr during the test and set [the `outputPerTestCase` property](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/JUnitXmlReport.html#setOutputPerTestCase-boolean-) as follows:

```
// (configuring the default `test` task of the `java` plugin here; works with
// any task of Gradle’s `Test` type, though)
test {
    reports {
        junitXml {
            outputPerTestCase = true
        }
    }
}
```

The written output will then end up at least *somewhere* within the `<testcase/>` element and you might be able use it from there somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, I'll try this out and see where it goes. I am accepting this answer for now.